# What is the difference between "(.....);" and "{......}" in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I am getting error shown in image for the below code:

```
handlechange(event) {
    this.setState (prevState => {
      return(
      checked : !prevState.checked
    );});
}
```

But when I changes round brackets after "return" into curly, it runs fine. I mean what's happening under the hood? What causes the error to go away?

```
handlechange(event) {
    this.setState (prevState => {
      return{
      checked : !prevState.checked
    }});
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Image isn't showing so I am  just pasting error here in comments.  "Parsing error: Unexpected token" at exclamation mark in "checked : !prevState.checked"

Comment: Well one is function call and another is object literal

Comment: @CodeManiac - `()` after `return` don't form a function call.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh yes. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a React thing. Your first example is just invalid JavaScript syntax.¹ Your second example is valid syntax, returning an object created via an object initializer (often called an object "literal," `{checked: !prevState.checked}`).

---

¹ The `()` after `return` wrap an expression, and then within the expression you have `checked: !prevState.checked` which looks like a labelled statement. But you can't put a labelled statement where an expression is expected.

---

Side note: Another way to write that is to use property destructuring in the parameter list and a shorthand property in the object initializer:

```
handlechange(event) {
    this.setState(({checked}) => {
      checked = !checked;
      return {checked};
    });
}
```

Comment: what is significance of ({..}) in second line of your code. Curly brackets signifies JS object but what about round braces?

Comment: In an arrow function, if the parameter list is anything more complicated than a simple parameter list containing just one parameter name, you have to put the list in `()`. So for instance, `a => { /* ... */}` is a correct arrow function, but `a, b => { /* ... */ }` is not, because it needs `()` around the parameter list: `(a, b) => { /* ... */ }`. In the second line of code above, since I'm using destructuring in the parameter list (`{checked}`), it's not a simple parameter list anymore, so the list has to be in `()`.

Comment: Bigger picture: What that destructuring does is pluck the value of the `checked` property out of the argument passed to the `setState` callback and put it in a parameter called `checked`. So `this.setState(({checked}) => { /* ... */ })` is effectively the same as `this.setState(prevState => { let checked = prevState.checked; /* ... */ })`

Answer (score 0):

In the case that is working correctly, you are returning a JavaScript object (defined by the curly braces).  That appears to be what you want to do, given the property-colon-value notation you are using, but the curly braces are required to signify the object in JavaScript.

```
{
    key: value
}
```

is a legal object definition, but

```
(
    key: value
)
```

is not.